# Mediawiki list of links on the page

Tags: mediawiki

How to create list of links on the page?

```
Article

[http://link1 My link]
...
http://link2 is good place

List of links:
* link1
* link2
...
```

Comment: Where do you need to show this list? What do you need this for? Are you looking for a plugin?

Comment: Plugin or native way, not important. I need it for quick search through page with many links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API call query for prop=extlinks to get all links out of the wiki in one call:   /w/api.php?action=query&prop=extlinks&titles=YourArticle

Example in the English Wikipedia API sandbox: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=extlinks&format=json&ellimit=10&titles=Stack%20Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=query&prop=extlinks&format=json&ellimit=10&titles=Stack%20Overflow)

Comment: Also, for internal links one can use {{Special:WhatLinksHere/{{FULLPAGENAME}}}}.